# What is the correct function expression for the given graph and it's Fourier series?

Tags: functions, graphing-functions, periodic-functions

[image]

I first thought it was $$x\left(t\right)=\frac{4}{T}t$$ for $$0<t<T/4$$

But that would be the case if it wasn't periodic, then i thought that it was:

$x\left(t\right)=\frac{4}{T}\left(t-T\right)$

But i'm not sure, and don't know how to plot it on graphing software to test it out. Can someone help me out?

EDIT: The problem I had at hand is to find the Fourier series for this function and I tried for both the functions I had written here earlier, but neither got me the right solution, so I'm not sure now.

Here is what I did so far:
[image]
[image]

Comment: Define a function on $[0,T]$ and then continue it periodically to the rest of $\mathbb{R}$. You can write down a Fourier series for it if you want an expression where the periodicity is explicit, but just stating the function on $[0,T]$ and saying "periodically continued" is also fine.

Comment: Actually my real task is to find the Fourier seris for that function, I tried a few times and failed to get the result in the solution, so I figured that the expression I got was wrong. So how would I find the Fourier series here?

Comment: Then add that to the question: both the problem statement as you wrote above and your try!

Comment: @Winther I uploaded what I tried so far, EDIT: but the last two images are in reversed order.

Comment: You have the right expression for $x(t)$ and the result you get looks kind off what I expect to see. If I run it through [WA](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7BT%7D%5Cint_0%5E%7BT%2F4%7D%5Cfrac%7B4t%7D%7BT%7De%5E%7B-2%5Cpi+i+n+t+%2FT%7D+dt) I get $c_n = \frac{(-i)^n (\pi n i - 2i^n + 2)}{2 \pi^2 n^2}$ which you can compare your answer to (note that $(-i)^n = e^{-\pi i n /2}$ and $(-1)^n = e^{\pi i n}$). Note that I here use the convention $x(t) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty c_n e^{2\pi i n t/T}$ so that $c_n = \frac{1}{T}\int_{0}^T x(t) e^{-2\pi i n t/T}{\rm d}t$.